# Using VBS to read from one text file and compare to CSV to create condition dependent shortcut

Tags: windows, vbscript, wsh

Trying to read a single value in a text file and use that value to match a position on a csv in order to generate a unique shortcut with arguments. I'm having trouble finding the error in my VBS logic in the script below:

```
dim objFS,objFileToRead,objTextFile, strSiteCode, strServerFQDN, strPort, mySiteCode
dim arrStr

strComputer = "."
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objTextFile = objFS.OpenTextFile("Servers.csv")
Set objFileToRead = objFS.OpenTextFile("code.txt",1)
Set mySiteCode = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


Do while NOT objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
  arrStr = Split(objTextFile.ReadLine,",")
  strSiteCode = arrStr(0)
  strServerFQDN = arrStr(1)
  strPort = arrStr(2)
  if mySiteCode = strSiteCode then
    'wscript.echo "Site Code: " & strSiteCode & " - Server FQDN: " & strServerFQDN & " - Port #: " & strPort
    fullname = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Generic\Generic.lnk"
    TargetPath = "%SystemRoot%\Generic\Generic.exe"
    Set shortcut = WSHShell.CreateShortcut(fullname)
    shortTarget = shortcut.TargetPath
    shortcut.Arguments = "s=" & strServerFQDN & " p=" & strPort
    shortcut.save
    fullname = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Generic.lnk"
     TargetPath = "%SystemRoot%\Generic\Generic.exe"
    Set shortcut = WSHShell.CreateShortcut(fullname)
    shortTarget = shortcut.TargetPath
    shortcut.Arguments = "s=" & strServerFQDN & " p=" & strPort
    shortcut.save
  end if
Loop
```

I'm wondering if I need to load both the csv and txt file in to an array in order to create the shortcut with the correct information.

Resources:

servers.csv (file contains info in format below)

Site1,10.0.0.1,12345
Site2,10.0.0.2,23456
...

code.txt (file contains only one line which is site identifier)

Site1

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem? What error do you get?

Comment: No error, it was just blowing by without generating the icons...

Answer (score 0):

If you'd execute the script from an open cmd window with

```
cscript YourScriptName.vbs
```

you will see the error message. I think you should change the lines

```
shortTarget = shortcut.TargetPath
```

to

```
shortcut.Target = TargetPath
```

or better directly to

```
shortcut.Target = "%SystemRoot%\Generic\Generic.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue wasnt that the file wasnt getting generated, but that the Site1 wasnt picking up and populaitng the proper arguments. I made some changes and Have this version working. Had to format the inout with a trim() command as the text file held the Site1 code with a Carriage Return that was preventing the array from picking up a match.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a reply to LotPings (thanks for your feedback!) the issue was that the readall command was picking up the contents of the text file to include the CRLF at the end of the Site1 value. It was not obvious that these characters were present until opening the txt file in an editor that would display all characters.

Corrected and functional code is:

```
dim objFS,objFileToRead,objTextFile, strSiteCode, strServerFQDN, strPort, mySiteCode
dim arrStr

strComputer = "."
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objTextFile = objFS.OpenTextFile("Servers.csv")
Set objFileToRead = objFS.OpenTextFile("code.txt",1)
mySiteCode = objFileToRead.ReadLine()
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do while NOT objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
  arrStr = Split(objTextFile.ReadLine,",")
  strSiteCode = arrStr(0)
  strServerFQDN = arrStr(1)
  strPort = arrStr(2)
  if trim(mySiteCode) = trim(strSiteCode) then
    'Start Menu Icon Creation Here
    fullname = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Generic\Generic.lnk"
    Set shortcut = WSHShell.CreateShortcut(fullname)
    shortcut.TargetPath = "%SystemRoot%\Generic\Generic.exe"
    shortcut.Arguments = "s=" & strServerFQDN & " p=" & strPort
    shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "%SystemRoot%\Generic"
    shortcut.save
    'Desktop Icon Creation Here
    fullname = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Generic.lnk"
    Set shortcut = WSHShell.CreateShortcut(fullname)
    shortcut.TargetPath = "%SystemRoot%\Generic\Generic.exe"
    shortcut.Arguments = "s=" & strServerFQDN & " p=" & strPort
    shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "%SystemRoot%\Generic"
    shortcut.save
  Exit Do
 end if
 Loop
```